# Is it a good practice to pass the reference of a controller to a service and modify the data in view directly from service?

Tags: angularjs

Let me explain it with an example.

**Controller** :

```
app.controller('myController', function(){

  var refCtrl = this;

  refCtrl.employeeName = 'Bill';
  refCtrl.employeeAge  = 25;

  myService.changeNameAndAge(refCtrl);

});
```

Now the employeeName and employeeAge variables are bounded to the View (HTML).

**Service** :

```
app.factory('myService',function(){

   return {

      changeAgeAndName : function(ref) {

          if(some_business_logic_condition_check) {
             ref.name = 'Harry';
             ref.age = 30;
          }
      }
  };
});
```

Now, we can use this service to change the values of name and age in the view.

It is happening successfully. But is it a good practice? Does it not break the MVC pattern?

Comment: It looks strange... a bit cleaner solution would be to use `angular.extend` / `$.extend` / `_.extend` to augment your target object (controller) with data returned from service.

Comment: imo bad practice it's like passing the $scope to the service

Comment: What are you gaining by doing this? What's the point of the controller? Service should be designed to be used across controllers (or even apps) - all you did is created an unnecessary level of indirection.

Comment: the service should work like static function's on server side, take input and give output... what you pass, should be minimum required params so that its easy to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to have a loose coupling between the MVC layers. In the given code, if the controller is altered, then the service too will need a change, thereby making every change immensely complex.